# getting vector-tags pair after training in words2vec

Tags: python, parsing, doc2vec

I am trying to convert a bunch of poems into vectors, and then use my own implementation of k-means on them, but I can't figure out how to get the vectors with tags attached after training in doc2vec. I also find that when I train on 11 files I get 14 back out (I would like the same number of vectors in as out obviously).

My code takes in a path to a folder with a few text files in it. Right now I am just printing the vectors given by `learner.docvecs`, and have no idea which vector is which.

Code:

```
import os
import gensim

def parse_doc2vec(direc):

    # gets list of file names
    files = os.listdir(direc)

    translator = str.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)

    tovecpoems=[]

    count = 0
    for filename in files:

        file = open(direc + "/" + filename)
        list = file.read().split(sep= "\n")
        subject = list[0].split(" ",1)[0]

        poem = list[3:]
        poem = ''.join(poem)
        poem = poem.split()
        for i in range (len(poem)):
            poem[i] = poem[i].replace('\t','').replace('\n','')
            poem[i] = poem[i].translate(translator)
            if poem[i] == '':
                poem.remove(poem[i])


        tovecpoem = gensim.models.doc2vec.LabeledSentence(words = poem, tags = [filename,subject])
        tovecpoems.append(tovecpoem)
        count += 1


    learner = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(tovecpoems,alpha=0.025, min_alpha=0.025)

    for epoch in range(10):
        learner.train(tovecpoems,total_examples = learner.corpus_count, epochs = learner.iter)
        learner.alpha -= 0.002
        learner.min_alpha = learner.alpha


    vectors = learner.docvecs

    for vec in vectors:
        print(vec,'\n')
```

If someone could please tell me how to retrieve vectors with `filename` attached from `tags`, and why `vectors` has more objects in it then `tovecpoems`does, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should show what your code is printing, to let answerers know what's not appearing correct from what you see.

You're supplying `Doc2Vec` with 10 text examples, but every text example you're providing has 2 `tags`: `tags=[filename, subject]`. So the 4 extra `tags`, that aren't filenames, are probably unique values of `subject` that repeat.

Separately, it's a bad idea to try to manage `alpha`/`min_alpha` yourself, or call `train()` multiple times in your own loop. Just leave those values as their defaults, use `Doc2Vec`'s `iter` parameter to specify how many training passes you want.

And by providing `tovecpoems` as an argument to `Doc2Vec`, you've already triggered training - there's no need to call `train()` at all. (If you'd not supplied the corpus already, it would make sense to call `build_vocab()` and `train()` exactly once each, but no more.)

So for example your code would make more sense as just:

```
learner = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(tovecpoems, iter=10)
vectors = learner.docvecs
# ...etc
```

Note that you won't get a good `Doc2Vec`/`Word2Vec` results from tiny toy-sized datasets. They generally need many thousands of examples (containing hundred-of-thousands to millions of words) to obtain the sort of vector-qualities people usually want from them. (You can sometimes squeeze a little demo-able value out of a small dataset by (1) shrinking the model vector `size` radically; and (2) increasing the number of `iter` training-passes, but that's hit-or-miss.)

Comment: I now have replaced my code with your code starting after, `tovecpoems.append(tovecpoem)`, and I get a `RuntimeError: you must first build vocabulary before training the model` on `learner = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(tovecpoems, iter=10)`.

Also, what I would really like to have as output would be: `[[[vector],[tag]],[[vector],[tag]],...]`. Or something in a similar format but with tuples as pairs etc...

Comment: If you replaced the code properly, there are no more calls to `train()` in your code – that is, nothing between `learner = …` line and the `vectors = …` line. Show what your code is printing if you want answerers to understand the difference between what you're seeing and what you want/expect.

Comment: output: `[-0.39454716, -0.13693427, -0.78301853]
[-1.23432457, -0.1715124,  -2.46840692]
[-1.02292275, -0.10415638, -2.05834198]...
`

wanted:
`[[vector],[tags]]
[[vector],[tags]]...`

Comment: It appears that I can use `vectors.index_to_doctag(index)` to retrieve the tag for the given `index`, so that will work.